# Find Reports On A Specific Object?

Tags: reporting

I am trying to hunt down Reports on a specific object and having trouble finding this information anywhere. The [`Report`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_report.htm) object does not seem to have any fields that indicate the Report Type, nor any other indicators as to what object the Report is built on.

Is this information accessible? Is there any way to find all reports of a specific type, or on a specific object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select `Reports and Dashboard`, the following fields are available from `Reports` entity:

- `Report Type`
- `Custom Entity: Object Name`
- `Child Entity: Object Name`

I'm not sure if with this type you are only limited to the reports used on dashboard components...

Comment: Strange that the `Report Type` field doesn't show up on a Report with the `Reports` Report Type. I wonder why `Dashboards` are even relevant there...

Comment: I was thinking the same. Technically `Report` object have to expose the same number of fields related to `Report` available on this `Reports and Dashboard` report type if not more.

Comment: It doesn't even seem to be a field on `Report`, though, according to the documentation nor the Schema. Mysterious...

Comment: I had this experience when the fields where not covered in the documentation for `ContentVersion` (however they were available on Schema), and it took rounds of Support to work on the case to even find the right internal group to fix this, and I even stopped tracking if it was complete after a couple months of waiting. Salesforce Support is almost unavailable for some unusual technical things, and they tend to work with you to close the case before it's being fixed to get out from the radar.

Comment: Does this still exist? I'm only seeing "Report" and "Dashboard" options for report type options, no "Reports and Dashboards" report type options. Checked both classic and lightning report builders, same result ...